# RxJS finalize(): pass the last emitted value to the callback

Tags: angular, rxjs, angular-services, finalize

In my Angular service,  I've got a `loading` prop which I set `true` as a first thing done in the method fetching data. I want to set `loading` to false after the data is downloaded. I was doing it in `finalize()`:

```
public fetch: (type: myType, page?: number) => Observable<any> = (
type: myType,
page: number = 1
  ) => {
    return this.serviceFor(type)
      .fetchList(page, this.queryParams)
      .pipe(
        map(({ data, meta }) => {
          return ({ collectionName: type, collection: data, meta })
        }),
        finalize(() => {
          this.loading.next(false)
        })
      );
  };
```

Now, I have three `loading` props, each one corresponding to a different type.
I would like to pass `type`(collectionName) to finalize.
Since `finalize()` doesn't take any aguments, it there any other way to take last emitted value and do something with it when stream is done?

```
finalize((collectionName) => {
      switch (collectionName)
         ...
    })
```

Linked topic:
https://github.com/ReactiveX/rxjs/issues/4803

EDIT:
Question is answered in the comment by kruschid.

Comment: since `collectionName` is the same as  `type` why not using the latter inside the `finalize` body?

Comment: What's the problem with `tap()` as explained in the linked issue? We could argue, that `finalize()` is called after all values are emitted and so there can't be value at that time. To find a better solution, some more context why you need the last value would help.

Comment: @kruschid Thanks! That's a perfect solution and that's what I need.

Comment: @ChristophLütjen The kruschid 's  answer above is perfectly what I wanted.

Comment: @ChristophLütjen  Although I still think that the question could be interesting. Yes, let's say that someone needs to do something according to the last emitted value, after all values are emitted and a method is used and subscribed to in many places. So it would be more comfortable to code what to do in the method not in the separate subscriptions.

Comment: We often know that our observable emits 0-1 values, in this cases `tab()` should do the job. Another option would be the `last()` operator. A little bit more work, but now you have an observable that emits once with the last value. See https://www.learnrxjs.io/learn-rxjs/operators/filtering/last

Answer (score 2):

```js
function finalizeWithValue<T>(callback: (value: T) => void) {
  return (source: Observable<T>) => defer(() => {
    let lastValue: T;
    return source.pipe(
      tap(value => lastValue = value),
      finalize(() => callback(lastValue)),
    )
  })
}
```

[Source](https://github.com/ReactiveX/rxjs/issues/4803#issuecomment-496711335)

Comment: The purpose of `defer` is to keep separate state for each subscriber. Because `finalize` is called not just when the observable completes but also when the subscriber unsubscribes, this ensures--for the latter case--the callback will be called for each subscriber with the current value at the time of each unsubscription.

Answer (score 0):

I would use a tap operator to do whatever you need with the emmited value, and keep the finalize just for setting loading to false. You might need to check last operator also. A combination of them should be enough.